# How to Deserialize XML with Same Attribute Name in 2 Different Element?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

My class definition:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ID")] //Problem is here. same attr name ID.
    public int XXX_ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "XXX")]
    public string XXX_Value{ get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ID")] //Problem is here. same attr name ID.
    public int YYY_ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "YYY")]
    public string YYY_Value { get; set; }
}
```

My XML:

```
<MyClass>
    <XXX ID="123">Some Values</XXX> 
    <YYY ID="567">Some Values</YYY>
</MyClass>
```

My Problem:

I want to de-serialize the above XML into an object.

During the runtime, an error has occurred, it is not allowed to have same attribute name in 2 different elements and under the same root.

How to solve this problem?

P/S: I cannot change the XML, I am not the owner of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: `[Serializable]` does nothing useful here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you either need to do the (de)serialization manually, or you need to DTO to have roughly the same layout as the xml. For example:

```
public class Something { // need a name here to represent what this is!
    [XmlAttribute] public int ID {get;set;}
    [XmlText] public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

then

```
public class MyClass {
    public Something XXX {get;set;}
    public Something YYY {get;set;}
}
```